# HTTP 403 Service Error when trying to post XML to HTTPS URL

Tags: java, https, httpclient

I am trying to write a small class using the Apache HttpClient library that would do an HTTPS post to a specified URL sending some XML. When I run my code, the HTTP status line I receive back is "403 Service Error". Here's the complete error HTML returned:

```
$errorDump  java.net.SocketTimeoutException:Read timed out
$errorInfo  
$errorDump  java.net.SocketTimeoutException:Read timed out
$error  Read timed out
$localizedError Read timed out
$errorType  java.net.SocketTimeoutException
$user   
$time   2011-10-25 09:39:29 EDT
$error  Read timed out
$errorType  java.net.SocketTimeoutException
```

This is the code I am using:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.InputStreamEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class HttpXmlPost {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String url = "https://someurlhere.com";
        String xmlStr = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?><xmlTag></xmlTag>";

        String content = request(xmlStr, url);
        System.out.println(content);
    }

    private static String request(String xmlStr, String url) {
        boolean success = false;
        String content = "";

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        try {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url.trim());

            InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlStr.getBytes() ), -1);
            reqEntity.setContentType("application/xml");
            reqEntity.setChunked(true);

            httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);

            System.out.println("Executing request " + httpPost.getRequestLine());
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){
                success = true;
            }
            if (resEntity != null) {
                System.out.println("Response content length: " + resEntity.getContentLength());
                System.out.println("Chunked?: " + resEntity.isChunked());
            }

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resEntity.getContent()));
            StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
            char[] cbuf = new char[ 2048 ];
            int num;

            while ( -1 != (num=reader.read( cbuf ))) {
                buf.append( cbuf, 0, num );
            }

            content = buf.toString();

            EntityUtils.consume(resEntity);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        finally {
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }

        return content;
    }
}
```

Whatever XML I pass in doesn't seem to matter, it gives the same error no matter what. Note that this actually works with some URLs. For example, if I put https://www.facebook.com, it goes through. However, it doesn't work for my specified URL. I thought it might be a certificate issue, tried to add some code to trust any certificate, didn't seem to work either, though I may have done it wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [`SocketTimeoutException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/SocketTimeoutException.html) in the first line of the response HTML, I'm guessing that the component which implements the handler for the URL to which you are posting is having some connection problems to a source system it needs to generate the response data.

Basically, it looks like the problem is on the server, not your client.

Comment: What's strange is that if I try to just access the link in the browser, it works. Granted, this is a POST and the browser does a GET, but it's still weird. To give some more background, I'm basically trying to replace a CFHTTP call made in ColdFusion to this Java call because with ColdFusion I keep having to re-import certificates to the keystore all the time for some URLs, which isn't practical. With Java I should be able to code something to ignore certificate errors, but I'm not even getting to the point where I get a certificate error.